# Static cast on non-references

Tags: c++, static-cast

Consider the following program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Pet {};

class Cat: public Pet {
public:
    void meow() const {
        std::cout << "Meow!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Cat myCat;    
    Pet& myPet = myCat;
    static_cast<Cat&>(myPet).meow();
    
    // Undefined behavior?
    Pet myOtherPet;
    static_cast<Cat&>(myOtherPet).meow();
}
```

On my machine, the output is:

```
Meow!
Meow!
```

As expected, `myPet` is able to `meow()` just fine, since it is not just any `Pet&`, but it was assigned the value `myCat`, which is of class `Cat`.

However, to my surprise `myOtherPet` is also able to `meow()`. I can speculate that since `meow()` doesn't use any class data, the program is just letting me use my generic pet as a cat.

To make matters worse, consider the following program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Person {};

class Student: public Person {
public:
    float Average = 28.7;
    void print() const {
        std::cout << "Average: " << Average << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {    
    Person& myPerson = myStudent;
    static_cast<Student&>(myPerson).print();
    
    // Undefined behavior?
    Person myOtherPerson = myStudent;
    static_cast<Student&>(myOtherPerson).print();
}
```

On my machine, the output is:

```
Average: 28.7
Average: 0
```

This time `myOtherPerson`, who is not a student, has just magically gotten `Average` data attached to it.

- Is this behavior consistent across compilers or undefined?
- Can such use cause segmentation faults?

Comment: what do you mean "on non references"?

Comment: You are casting from an lvalue, so treating the casted objects as references.

Comment: "*myOtherPerson, who is not a student, has just magically gotten Average data attached to it*" - No, it has not. The `print` call invokes undefined behavior, and getting a garbage value like `0` printed is one possible manifestation of such UB.

Answer (score 3):

The two legal use cases for `static_cast` with references are when there is already an implicit conversion sequence or when you downcast. This is neither of these cases since `myOtherPet` isn't actually a `Cat`. You can see the legal use cases for `static_assert` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast).

Both are undefined behavior. You are lying to the compiler by saying `myOtherPet` is a `Cat` and `myOtherPerson` is a `Student` while they are not. It might print "Meow!", it might crash, it might print arbitrary output or it might do something else.

---

- Is this behavior consistent across compilers or undefined?

It is Undefined Behavior.

- Can such use cause segmentation faults?

Any behavior is allowed for this code, including a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I think of `static_cast` as allowing normal implicit conversions *or their inverses*.  So why doesn't this object, saying you have to use `reinterpret_cast` instead?

Read through https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast

> If new_type is a reference or pointer to some class D and expression is lvalue of its non-virtual base B or prvalue pointer to it, static_cast performs a downcast. (This downcast is ill-formed if B is ambiguous, inaccessible, or virtual base (or a base of a virtual base) of D.) Such a downcast makes no runtime checks to ensure that the object's runtime type is actually D, and may only be used safely if this precondition is guaranteed by other means, ...

So, there is a base/derived relationship between the two types.  You are specifying a "downcast" and the compiler takes you at your word.  If the types were unrelated, the `static_cast` would indeed be rejected.  If you want type checking, you need to use `dynamic_cast` instead and have virtual functions so the run-time checking is *possible*.